# customizing firefox webfonts in userContent.css

Tags: firefox, fonts, css

Sometimes when I am on some webpages Firefox keeps using some fonts that ends me up with tiny squares around the corner, I solved the problem using userContent.css file with these options:

```
*
{
    font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}

pre, code, samp, tt, var
{
    font-family: Consolas !important;
}
```

All is fine except sometimes some webpages still keep showing strange and unlikable behaviour like showing Google results and wikipedia pages in Times New Roman font, is there a way to tell firefox in userContent.css to use different fonts, like first use FontAwesome, if you didn't find a character, then use SegoiUI for normal text, then use Arial unicode, then use freeSans if you still could not find your needed character and so on???
Is it even possible in CSS?

bless you all thank you so much

P.S: also using this specific usercontent.css file that I have created question lines on this very website are not bold  faced. is there a way to tell mozilla to sometimes use the style of the webpages along with my fonts?

Comment: the solution for first problem i think that is related on fonts installed on your machine. what OS are you using? changing the default fonts for the sites on browser doesn't scale very well and should be annoying

Comment: @ emirjonb Hi, I am using windows 8.1 64bit edition. And I do not suppose the problem is with the fonts, but I am not an expert. Also why do you think it is not good practice to control this using userContent.css?

Comment: First because every site/browser are used worldwide without problems. You can use your custom fonts nothing dangerous or harmful but modern sites have complex composition and designs and custom fonts destroy the beauty of the site :/. anyway try here if you have all the fonts: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Fonts  i currently have 257 font listed. or you can give a url that your browser render with font error

Comment: Ok I removed my custom css file, that I worked on for almost a long time to make my Firefox look cool, like that beautiful Anonymous background that I had for new pages is now gone, but the original problem is still around. even on this very webpage belonging to superuser.com I am getting Italic and bold faced fonts, when I right click on them it says that it is using "Helvetica 96 Black Italic" font face.... ;( ;( ;( ;( ;(; ;( ;( ;(

Comment: Help me people.... pleasee ;(

Comment: Can you use another browser just to test if everything is going well with your PC. Second if you have changed firefox settings you sure have messed something up. so just install firefox from a fresh installer